# How do I bind buttons to zoom and workspace switcher in Unity?

Tags: unity, 12.10, compiz

Previously I used compiz-config for button bindings.  I keep hearing that Compiz does not work well with Unity.  Is there a way to bind buttons to zoom and workspace switcher without using Compiz?

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, Unity is often said not to play well with compiz-config (CCSM), right? Unity works a lot better with Compiz than without ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear for me because you seem to mix up Compiz and CCSM ("Compiz-config"). I'm assuming that you still want to use Compiz, but just don't want to use CCSM.

### Approach 1: alternative front-end to Compiz

CCSM is a front-end for the settings in Compiz. There are a few others available (OMG!Ubuntu covered a few of them in the past year or so, see e.g. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/introducing-unity-tweak-tool) that ought to be safer. Try this first.

### Approach 2: Directly alter settings through GConf

Alternatively, you can take the difficult path and "go commando". You won't need a front-end for Compiz if you access the GConf settings, where the Compiz settings are stored. You could do this with the command line but are probably better off using some GUI for GConf. Try using `gconf-editor`, that allows you to change the Compiz settings. Simply go to `/apps/compiz-1/plugins/wall/screen0/options` if you want to change the Desktop Wall settings, for example. If you then change the value of the key `/apps/compiz-1/plugins/wall/screen0/options/down_key` you can change the value of the key to switch to your workspace below. All otherCompiz plugins are available in a similar directory.

Although you didn't ask: To be honest, I'd just use CCSM if I were you. Yes, if something goes wrong you can destroy your settings, but that's nothing you can fix without resetting your Compiz/Unity profile (search around a bit for this, e.g. look at [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)). You'll lose your Compiz settings in that case, but not your data. If you're careful not to mess around too much you should be okay. Also, the second approach is probably much more dangerous than CCSM.